# Using Linq to return groupId

Tags: c#, linq

I have this class :

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public int GroupId { get; set; }     
}
```

How do I do if I want to return `GroupId` if I have given `Id` .. like

```
public Person GetGroupId (int id)
{
    return  _context.Person.Where(c => c.Id == id)
                           .Select(x =>  x.GroupId)
                           .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But this giving me error message like "cannot implicitly convert type".

Answer (score 3):

The type returned by the query does not match the return type defined by the method.

Update the method to return the desired type, which in this case is `int`

```
public int GetGroupId (int id) {
    return  _context.Person.Where(c => c.Id == id).Select(x => x.GroupId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: This will lead to issue with null value from `FirstOrDefault`, you may as well return `int?` or `Person`